# Android, Is it possible to put two different activities in screen of tablets using Fragment?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

According to my research abut fragment, fragments are using when we have Title/description based contents, such as books, magazine, etc.

Some projects are not title/description base. In this situation can we use fragments? 
for example, assume that we have 10" screen tablet and I want to show 4 different activity of my application inside screen while in handsets user with clicking on menus can see them.

is it possible to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yups, you can make as many activity on your screen as you want using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).

Fragments was developed by google as the screen size of tablet is large and we can accommodate more functionality in one screen. All work is done by FragmentManager. You can make an XML layout with as many fragment view you want in any pattern. Then associate all the view to an individual activity. Activity can communicate between each other also. More you can find in following examples.

1. http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragments_tutorial
2. http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html
3. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/

**EDIT**

What you need to do is get the width and height using following function.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    WindowManager w = getWindowManager();
    Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = d.getWidth();
    int height = d.getHeight();
```

Make different layout for different dimension of screen. Now keep if else loop to decide which layout to be set using `setContentView(R.id.layoutfor10inchtable)` etc.

For configuration change, make one boolean variable say permitConfigurationChange and when you are setting the view, you can also set this variable to true or false in if else loop.

The override onConfigurationChange method. In if check `if (permitConfigurationChange == false) return;`

Design part for layout, you need to see the tutorials, they will provide you all the details.

Comment: Thanks dear Raj, so, if its possible, The next question is how to manage it in different screen sizes? assume that in handset i just want to support portrate mode with one activity, in tablet 7" i just want to support landscape with 2 activities and finally in 10" i just want to support landscape with 4 activities. is it possible? sorry if i'm asking stupid question, but fragment is a little bit strange for me :)

Comment: Its my pleasure to answer you. :) Do you want to one app that would work on all devices or different app for different devices?

Comment: No Not different app. Just one app that is runable on all devices in term that I mentioned above. its better to separate my question into two questions. 1) can we configure our application in a way that on hand set devices just run in portrate mode and in tablets run in landscape mode? currently in manifest if you set orientation on landscape this configuration apply to all devices (which i want handsets support portrate mode not landscape.

Comment: 2) Can I get width of device in runtime and based of that width assign fragments to that activity? for example if (device == 7") { loade_Fragment_A(); load_fragment_B();} else if (device == 10") {loade_Fragment_A(); loade_Fragment_B(); loade_Fragment_C(); loade_Fragment_D();}

Comment: Thanks again 1000 times :) for your help

Answer (score 0):

1、You can use fragment instead of Activity. (Not really instead)..

Answer (score 0):

At first Fragments are not used to display Title/description type pages only.
Instead, Fragments are activity component which can work independenty, irrespective of other components on the activity. Fragments also can maintain their own backstack. So, Its always possible to have four fragments on one screen/activity. What you need to do, create four classes, which extends Fragment not Activity, and Add these fragments to MainActivity.