# How to use two activites in a single screen in android?

Tags: android

I want to display two different activities in a single screen how can i do that in android?Please if anybody has idea share it.And I don't wanna use fragments.

I want to display a screen which contains some fields and below(at the bottom of the screen)  I want another screen with some buttons.

Is this possible in android?

If so, How can i do this ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use fragments? They're pretty much designed for stuff like this.

Comment: What's the reason you are not using Fragments?

Comment: You could use ActivityGroup for this purpose. But it is deprecated since 13 api, so you should use Fragments

Comment: you can go through this link [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424266/android-is-it-possible-to-put-two-different-activities-in-screen-of-tablets-usi

Comment: @user3350830 Y not fragment?The main purpose of fragment is to split screen(Activity) in multiple parts.

Answer (score 4):

You can't have two activities in one screen. You can have only one. So, ultimate solution is [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

An activity is not directly a visual component, so I'm thinking that what you're really asking is how to have a single activity display different views.

There's nothing that says you can't rerun `setContentView()` with a different layout/view ID. But there's another non-fragments way of doing what your probably want.

You can define more than one full-size (match_parent) view in a layout. What you want to do is set the visibility for one of them to "visible" with `android:visibility="visible"` and all the others to "gone" with `android:visibility="gone"`.

Then when you want to switch the displayed view, you'll run `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on the outgoing view and `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` on the incoming. It's important to use GONE and not INVISIBLE or the layouts won't render correctly.

### Sample layout file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>
```

### Sample Code to switch view:

```
video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
web.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

That said, you probably want to learn how to use fragments since you can handle switching the view along with other state in a single unit of work (a transaction). But the above approach above does work for simple view changes.